# Filtering with multiple tables using NOTORM PHP

Tags: php, mysql, notorm

Two Tables defined as below:

```
----------   Table1 -----------
 id      type    
 1        A
 2        B
 3        C

----------  Table2 ----------
id   type    sub_type
1     A      sub_type1
2     B      sub_type1
3     C      sub_type2
4     A      sub_type3
5     B      sub_type2
```

I want to find out all types which have subTypes `sub_type1` or `sub_type3`, my code is as below:

```
$SubCategoryFilterArray = ['sub_type1','sub_type3'].

$query = $db->table1();
function SubCategoryFilteredQuery($SubCategoryFilterArray , $query){

  $filterSubArrayQuery = '';
  for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($SubCategoryFilterArray); $i++){
    if($i>0)
        $filterSubArrayQuery .= ' OR ' ;
    $filterSubArrayQuery .= $db->table2()->where(' sub_type = "' . $SubCategoryFilterArray[$i].'" ')->select('type');

  }

 //    $q = $db->table2()->where($p)->select('type');
 return $query->where('type', $filterSubArrayQuery);  // doubt
}

$finalQuery  = SubCategoryFilteredQuery($SubCategoryFilterArray , $query);
echo count($finalQuery);
```

Comment: What result are you getting with this code?

Comment: I am getting nothing just no results at all.